# How to Cross Build Latest Stable Qemu with x86_64-w64-mingw32

Tags: package-management, cross-compilation

Installed the mingw and cloned the "latest stable" branch of [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) with

```
sudo apt-get install -y mingw-w64
cd ~/
git clone -b stable-2.2 git://git.qemu.org/qemu.git
cd ~/qemu
```

Then from @http://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/W32#Building_QEMU_for_W64 I tried:

```
./configure --cross-prefix=amd64-mingw32msvc-
```

and now I'm getting:

```
ERROR: "amd64-mingw32msvc-gcc" either does not exist or does not work
```

Update:

```
~/Scripts/qemu$ ./configure --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32-
ERROR: pkg-config binary 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config' not found
```

2nd Update:

Fixed previous issue with

```
sudo link /usr/bin/pkg-config /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends -y build-dep qemu
```

but now I'm getting:

```
owner@K53TA:~/qemu$ ./configure --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32-

ERROR: zlib check failed
       Make sure to have the zlib libs and headers installed.
```

but `zlib1g-dev` IS INSTALLED

Comment: 2 Questions: 1. Are you trying to build Qemu for Windows?  2. Have you installed the mingw compiler?

Comment: @eyoung100 yes, and yes.

Comment: Why not Consider using [WinQemu](http://winqemu.sourceforge.net/)?  What your doing, they've already done using VC2008.  If you insist on Cross Compiling, 2 more questions: 1. Is your build host 64-bit? 2. Is your Windows Install 32-bit?

Comment: @eyoung100 why would I use VC2008, when I can use ubuntu from a VM? I'm interested in compiling it, not just downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

### Warning: This answer is a Work In Progress

Even though I asked the OP to consider using [WinQemu](http://winqemu.sourceforge.net/), I'm officially writing an answer for those that choose to "do it from scratch."  Assuming your build host is 64-bit and your Windows is 32-bit:

1. We need to remove the OP's failed install of the cross-compile tools, using:
   `sudo apt-get --purge remove mingw-w64`
   `rm -vR ~/qemu`
2. Now we must decide on our Architecture.  **If your Build host is 64-bit, and your Windows is 32-bit, use**:
   `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw32 mingw32-binutils mingw32-runtime`
3. **If your Build host is 64-bit, and your Windows is 64-bit, use**:
   `sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw32 mingw32-binutils mingw-w64`
4. Optional: Add SDL Support by:
   `wget http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32.tar.gz`
5. Now we [download](http://wiki.qemu.org/Download) the Source Tarball, and untar it.  You can also use the Git Clone as the OP did, but you only need to choose one option:
   `sudo apt-get install wget && wget http://wiki.qemu-project.org/download/qemu-2.2.0.tar.bz2 && tar -xvjpf qemu-2.2.0.tar.bz2 && cd qemu-2.2.0`
6. Now we configure the build. **If your Build host is 64-bit, and your Windows is 32-bit, use**:
   `configure --cross-prefix=i586-mingw32msvc- [--extra-cflags=-mthreads]`
7. **If your Build host is 64-bit, and your Windows is 64-bit, use**:
   `configure --cross-prefix=amd64-mingw32msvc-`

**Note**: If the Configure Phase fails, you must fix the configure errors, as the OP alluded to.  At this point, a configure failure is most likely caused by missing libraries

Comment: Under ubuntu 14.04 there is no package gcc-mingw32.  I tried with mingw32 and gcc-mingw-w64-i686 but after configure, I got : ERROR : pkg-config binary 'i586-mingw32msvc-pkg-config' not found

Comment: for ubuntu 14.04 use the command "sudo apt-get install mingw32 mingw32-binutils mingw32-runtime"